# Passing numpy.arange() an argument

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to pass the values that I want numpy.arange to use.

The code is:

```
for x in numpy.arange(argument)
```

where argument is:

argument = (.1,6.3,.1) (tuple)

TypeError: arange: scaler arguements expected instead of a tuple

arguement = [.1,6.3,.1] (list)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

arguement = '.1,6.3,.1' (string)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

and I've tried putting the tuple and list in a string. None of these have worked.

I've searched the literature and can find no reference to this.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arange` is like python's `range` function.

Perhaps you were looking for `numpy.array`?

Or maybe you really did want the range to be from 0.1 to 6.3 in steps of 0.1. In that case, use Python's argument unpacking syntax:

```
arguments = (.1, 6.3, .1)
numpy.arange(*arguments)
```

Comment: I had to change 'argument =...' to 'arguments =...' and then it worked. I'll have to read up on Python's argument unpacking sytax.
Thanks